# How do I add an event to gnome-calendar from the command line?

Tags: email, calendar, gnome-calendar

I use claws-mail and receive many invites to meetings in .ics files. In claws-mail I can define a command to open the file with. For example "evolution %s" adds it to my evolution calendar. Is there a similar command for gnome-calendar (I tried gnome-calendar %s, it ignores the filename totally).